# Solution to App Rejection Due to Unexpected Exit of an App in App Bundle Format During Testing

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

**[Background]**: I have submitted an AAB package for review, but the app was rejected due to unexpected exit after installation,this problem occurred only for app package on HUAWEI AppGallery.

**[Analysis]**

1. The log information indicated that the problem was caused by a missing third-party class.
   [image: See pic]
2. The developer checked the universal.apk file in the compiled AAB package but couldn't find the PropertyModulesKt class. However, the class existed in the original AAB package.
   [image: See pic]

This means that the resource file was lost when the AAB file was converted to universal.apk.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform App Bundle format (AAB packages) test locally before submitting an app for review. So once it goes thru all functions properly, you can verify universal package conversion is successful and submit an app in App Bundle format for review. Please check

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-aabtest-0000001059321484

This error might be related with proguard. Class might be there but obfuscated, so it has been renamed and can’t be found. Please check your proguard rules.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a test before submitting an app in App Bundle format for review.

For details, check this documentation:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-aabtest?ha_source=hms1